# How to close a socketConnection in R

Tags: r, sockets

When I open a socketConnection in R with the following code

```
con <- socketConnection(adress = my_adress, port = my_port, server=FALSE, open="r+b")
```

how can I close it again? Here is a list of functions which I already tried (in the comment behind each function is written why it did not work):

```
close(con) #Nothing happens or Error in close.connection(con) : invalid connection
con.close() #Error in con.close() : could not find function "con.close"
close.connection(con) #Nothing happens or Error in close.connection(con) : invalid connection
closeAllConnections() #Nothing happens
closeSocketClients() #Error in closeSocketClients() : could not find function "closeSocketClients"
unlink(con) #Nothing happens

on.exit(con) #Nothing happens
on.exit(socketConnection) #Nothing happens
close.socket(con) #Error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

rm(con) #Only removes it from the workspace, does not really close it
```

`close(con)` and `close.connection(con)` seem to do something, since "Nothing happens" is when I do it the first time after opening the connection and "Error..." is afterwards.

But the reason, why I am quite sure that none of the functions above *really* work, are messages like this:

```
Warning message:

In packFrameName(frame) : closing unused connection 3 (->IP-Adress:Port)
```

Comment: Err, just a crazy guess, but `con.close()`?

Comment: @EJP Thank you for your answer, but it results in `Error in con.close() : could not find function "con.close"`. I added it in my post.